# What is difference between using ffmpeg GOP setting or x264opt keyint combination?

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

Here is a ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -flags  +global_header -c:v  libx264 -vf scale="864x486",setsar=1:1,setdar=16:9 -profile:v main -level 31 -g 50 -keyint_min 50 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 700k -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k output2.mp4
```

and here is the other one:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -flags  +global_header -c:v  libx264 -vf scale="864x486",setsar=1:1,setdar=16:9 -x264opts keyint=50:min-keyint=50:no-scenecut -profile:v main -level 31 -b:v 700k -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k output2.mp4
```

Are there any differences between using `-g 50 -keyint_min 50 -sc_threshold 0` and `-x264opts keyint=50:min-keyint=50:no-scenecut` settings to gain constant keyframe interval?

Comment: Great question. For me, x264opts don't even seem to have any effect.